# Create table from Array

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, html-table

I am new in PHP. I found the usage of a simple foreach, but I want more advance.
What I done until now.
I am using the ''get'' form method to get some data from API integration.
This data I transform them to array. Every time I have more arrays.
Right now lets say I got 4967 arrays. After maybe I will have less or more.

So I am getting this

```
1 --> Login
2 --> Position ID
3 --> ....
4 --> ...
..
..
13 --> Margin
14 --> Login number (let's say 2005)
15 --> Position Id number (let's say 100)
```

So especially I want something like the below. Everytime to create one TR then 13 TH and looping it until the end

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Login</th>
<th>Position ID</th>
..
...
<th>Margin</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>12435</th>
<th>132321</th>
..
...
<th>2323</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>342243</th>
<th>345345</th>
..
...
<th>24324</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please if you have the kindness somehow give me guidelines with code. I am reading for 3 days and trying but unfortunately I can't do this.

The last thing I done in my php code to create the arrays is this

```
$array = explode('\r\n', $encodejson);
```

The output is this

```
array (
  0 => '"login',
  1 => 'positionId',
  2 => 'openTimestamp',
  3 => 'entryPrice',
  4 => 'direction',
  5 => 'volume',
  6 => 'symbol',
  7 => 'commission',
  8 => 'swap',
  9 => 'bookType',
  10 => 'stake',
  11 => 'spreadBetting',
  12 => 'usedMargin',
  13 => '3004701',
  14 => '394254',
  15 => '2018-07-19T23:23:53.733',
  16 => '1.2495',
  17 => 'BUY',
  18 => '300000.00',
  19 => 'GBPUSD',
  20 => '1.36',
  21 => '0.00',
  22 => 'BOOK_B',
  23 => '0.00',
  24 => 'false',
  25 => '5325.30',
```

0 - 12 is one tr th
13 -25 is another tr th

This happening  until the end (right now let's say I got 2483 arrays with this structure)

LAST UPDATE!!!
I done it with this way and worked

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 13);

    echo '<table id = "customers">';
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($chunk as $val) {
            printf('<td>%s</td>', $val);
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Thanks all guys for the help

Comment: please show us output of `var_export($array);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edit my original post. Please see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could tried to make chunks from the big array.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 13);
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
   //form the table here
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach($chuck as $value){
      echo "<th>".$value."</th>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

After modifying the flat array intu chunks you will have separated child array that simulate 1 row.

Comment: I can print it like this now [
        "\"login",
        "positionId",
        "openTimestamp",
        "entryPrice",
        "direction",
        "volume",
        "symbol",
        "commission",
        "swap",
        "bookType",
        "stake",
        "spreadBetting",
        "usedMargin"
    ],
    [
        "3004701",
        "394254",
        "2018-07-19T23:23:53.733",
        "1.2495",
        "BUY",
        "300000.00",
        "GBPUSD",
        "1.36",
        "0.00",
        "BOOK_B",
        "0.00",
        "false",
        "5325.30"
    ],

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend :) It was so easy :)